# how can i run multiple web applications on same ip using different ports

Tags: linux, chef-infra, openstack

openstack runs on ip address of the machine but chef server also demands to run on the same ip address on the web console. So what changes to be made to resolve this conflict on the linux os. What configuration files are required to be edited for openstack and chef server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both OpenStack and Chef Server are generally distributed and installed as appliances. Both expect to control the whole machine. As such, while this is possible, it is very not recommended. That said, if you have OpenStack at your disposal just install Chef Server in a VM and problem solved.